# How to use ndk-build without jni directory?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

We are attempting to add first class build support for Android to a C++ library. We want to supply a stock `Android.mk`, and disgorge it from dependencies like a `jni` subfolder in an Eclipse or Android Studio project directory. That is, we want to:

```
cd library-src
ndk-build <options>
```

In the above, `library-src` *is not* `NDK_PROJECT_PATH`. Rather, its the root folder for the library.

We visited the NDK's help (`ndk-build -?`), but it did not tell us how to remove the assumptions. We tried the following, but it produced an errors:

```
$ ndk-build -f Android.mk
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !    
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.    
/opt/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/build-local.mk:143: *** Android NDK: Aborting
Stop.
```

Attempting to set `NDK_PROJECT_PATH` results in a similar error:

```
$ NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. ndk-build -f Android.mk
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk    
/opt/android-ndk-r10e/.../add-application.mk:199: *** Android NDK: Aborting...
Stop.
```

And attempting to set `APP_BUILD_SCRIPT` results in a similar error:

```
$ NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk ndk-build -f Android.mk
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk    
/opt/android-ndk-r10e/.../add-application.mk:199: *** Android NDK: Aborting...
Stop.
```

How do we use ndk-build without the jni directory?

---

Its important that we remove the limitations/assumptions. If we can't remove them, then we can't automate building and testing. If we can't automate building and testing, then we can't add the support because our governance has some QA and testing gates that we won't be able to pass through. (I'm willing to tolerate a manual `adb push` to test on-device).

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that I don't understand your limitations. Why adding file `library-src/Android.mk` is OK, but `library-src/jni/Android.mk` breaks your QA and testing gates. Furthermore, **Android.mk** is usually not enough to launch a build. Whether you want to choose the STL variation, or ABI, or toolchain, it is natural to define these settings in a different file, **Application.mk**, which also goes to the **jni** directory by convention. Add **library-src/jni** directory, and Android developers will thank you when their tools of trade get upgrades and they can stay with the standard configuration.

But Android build is a very flexible system, and you can achieve literally what you ask for.

The experiments that you made did not work because **ndk-build** is simply a thin wrapper around GNU make, and treats environment variables with low priority.

```
ndk-build APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk NDK_PROJECT_PATH=.
```

will most likely simply work for you. If you need more control, you can use something like

```
ndk-build APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_STL=gnustl_static APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a APP_PLATFORM=android-19 NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9
```

You can control the output directories, too. See **NDK_APP_OUT**, **NDK_APP_LIBS_OUT**.

One last hint: if your global build process is based on **make**, you can invoke **$(MAKE)** directly instead of going through **ndk-build**. It is also OK if you require [*standalone toolchain*](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) to keep platform-independent **make** logic.

Comment: *"...I must admit that I don't understand your limitations..."* - there is no JNI directory, and we are not going to create one for Android's modified build system.

Comment: It is also OK if you require [*standalone toolchain*](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) instead of invoking **ndk-build**. You don't need to create a separate **Android.mk** file only for Android's modified build system!

Comment: `ndk-build APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk` - unfortunately, that did not work. `ndk-build` complained *"Android NDK: Could not find application project directory"*. But thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, in your scenario **NDK_PROJECT_PATH** is required. I fixed the answer.